# What is best way to check if a URL is valid in PHP?

Tags: php

3 and 4 also must be valid, how can I do it using `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`? `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` not understanding international domains.

```
1. $url = 'https://example.com'; - Valid
2. $url = 'https://example.com/en/'; - Valid
3. $url = 'https://example.հայ'; - Invalid
4. $url = 'https://example.рус'; - Invalid
5. $url = 'https://exa_mple.com'; - Invalid


if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
   echo("Valid URL!");
} else {
   echo("Invalid URL!");
}
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IDN function to first convert the IDN to ASCII:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php